# OpenSplice DDS subscriber does not receive data all the time

Tags: data-distribution-service

I have the following scenario when using OpenSplice DDS:

A publisher publishes a DDS topic instance continuously. A subscriber subscribes data using NoOpDataReaderListener, my test runs both publisher and subscriber at the same and the method `on_data_available`  of NoOpDataReaderListener in the subscriber print out the data content using `std::cout`.
My problem is that data is not printed out all the time when you run the test many runs even though the `on_subscription_matched` method of NoOpDataReaderListener is invoked during every run which indicating the matching of publisher and subscriber is successful. But the `on_data_available` does not always print out the data content.

Even I replace the data content printing out inside on_data_available with `std::cout` << `data do come in`, that message doesn’t appear all the time, only probably 7 out of 10 runs (7 runs all DDS samples can be seen from Subscriber, another 3 runs no DDS samples come out from Subscriber at all). So I think it is more to do with DDS problem instead of std out not being flushed out. Does anyone have idea or how to diagnostic DDS communication channel problem?

Some more information, with wireshark, I have observed the following:

it looks like whether the run is successful (subscriber successfully getting data from publisher) depends on if the user unicast port in publisher process can send data (RTPS DATA instead of just RTPS Heartbeat) to user multicast locator (239.255.0.1::multicast_port) in subscriber process.

Comment: With the limited description of your test, this question is hard to answer. A common cause of missing data is a publishing application writing data before the DataWriter has discovered the matching DataReader. This is a consequence of the asynchronous nature of discovery. Just a guess...

Comment: thanks Reinier, that make sense to me now. I need to figure out how to delay the publishing before ensuring the matching has happened. I wonder if there is any mechnism in OpenSplice allows me to do  that.

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. One option would be to set the DURABILITY QoS to TRANSIENT_LOCAL (as opposed to the default of VOLATILE). That way, the DataWriter delivers the update to the DataReader even if they discover each other after the initial write took place. Note that this approach does not involve "delaying the publisher". See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/54712261/1380680

Comment: Sorry Reinier, I have a look at my code again, the publisher is continuously printing out data, so even the DataReader miss the earlier data, it shouldn't miss the later though. I think I am back to square one

Comment: do you know any test tool that can help debuging OpenSplice, somewhere I read that there is ospltest, as part of the Votex build, I have the community version, don't seem have that ospltest or spltun inside.

Comment: Are you missing *all* data in some of the runs, or just some of the data is some of the runs? In the latter case, are you writing at full speed, or are you pausing in between writes?

Comment: missing all data in some of the runs, or all data appear in some of the runs